# indexOf to match a phrase and show an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect if my msg has `"No matching records found"` in it to do an `if/else` statement. I know the message has that phrase in it checking in the `console.log('msg', msg);`

Can someone please tell me if I have written this line incorrectly?

```
var hasNoRecords = msg.indexOf(/No matching records found/igm) > -1;
```

I am trying to show an *alert* if `hasNoRecords` finds that phrase in the message. But instead, it is bypassing the message as if it's not in the message.

```
if (hasNoRecords) {
      alert('There are no records found');
    } else {
      $('#pdfiframe').html(msg);
      document.getElementById('pdfiframe').contentWindow.print();
      console.log('hasNoRecords Failed');
    }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you execute your code with `var hasNoRecords = msg.indexOf(/No matching records found/igm) > -1;` what error do you get in the console?

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: Where are your quotes? `msg.indexOf("No matching records found")`

Comment: @GTown-Coder This is a regex. /.../igm ignores capitalization.

Comment: Please see [**String indexOf Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for examples how to use it.

Comment: try msg.match(/No matching records found/igm)

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't take regex's, try `search` instead.

Comment: @PaulStrobach why use a regular expression to ignore capitalization?  why not `msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("no matching records found")`

Comment: @GTown-Coder I don't now. Ask David Brierton

Comment: @GTown-Coder  That would fail always.. :)

Comment: @Keith lol sorry, changed the `N` to lowercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe `indexOf` accepts regular expressions, unless if you create your own custom function.  Furthermore, instead of using a regular expression to ignore capitalization you could use `.toLowerCase` on the string object to transform that object's value into all lowercase and then search for your value (which also has to be in all lower case).

Your current code could be changed to this:

```
var hasNoRecords = msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("no matching records found") > -1;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your HTML shouldn't have anything to do this.. you are concerned about whatever the value in `msg` is.  So post that, please.

Comment: You're welcome!  Just mark this answer as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered!